# Light sensor circuit

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-measurement, input

Hello for homework assignment I have to design an electric circuit which takes input from a light sensor and finds if the brightness is bigger than some value.

This is what I have done so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzaiIA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is the circuit working as expected?

Comment: Can you provide any information on the light sensor, such as the part number? It’s hard to tell what’s going on without that, but even at first glance, this looks a bit odd. That configuration is for a hysteresis comparator, meaning it will turn on if the light is over value ‘X’, but will turn off when the light goes below value ‘Y’. If that’s what you want, ok, but based on what you said it doesn’t sound like that.

Comment: provide the name or part no of your SENSOR , and use comparator instead of OP-AMP.

Comment: Deepak an opamp with positive feedback is a comparator.

Comment: Yes, but Comparator gives good speed, and the output can reach rail to rail. Its just suggestion but if you have just opamp around you, use it.

Comment: Is the circuit working  as expected? I don't know what you expected, so...